# efficient solution for dealing with huge datasets

Tags: performance, time-complexity, large-data

I have a dataset consisting of the apps used by users and I'm trying to find out the correlation between different apps. Currently, I have a dataset (a 1GB text file) relating to 200,000 users and 800,000 apps. I'm looking for an efficient way to build a matrix that shows the number of users that have installed particular apps together. For example, consider the following matrix:

```
      app1  app2  app3  app4
app1  0     100   300   50     
app2  100   0     350   0
app3  300   350   0     70
app4  50    0     70    0
```

The value 100 indicates the number of users who have app1 AND app2 installed (simultaneously) on their phone. For creating this matrix, I thought of first sorting/filtering (using Map/Reduce)/aggregating (in MongoDB) the main unsorted data file by userID (O(n)?), then for apps used by each user, having 2 nested loops to count the number of apps installed together (i.e. getting the values in the above matrix). But this is so expensive (**O(n^3)**?) and unscalable.

Of course I've thouh about multithreading and running the program on some cluster, but I need an **scalable and efficient algorithm/tool** in the first place (e.g. using dynamic programming?). I'm impressed with the performance of GNUPlot in large datasets, and I was hopeful that I can achieve similar performance.

My preference for the programming language is Java, but I've also thought about R (and related HPC packages) and also Bash, although I'm not familiar with R. I also thought about "graph databases", like Neo4J, but I'm not sure if they suit my problem at hand (I need graph visualization of my data in the future though).

Answer (score 2):

Have you thought through what you're trying to do?

There are 800000 apps.  An 800000 x 800000 matrix will take almost 5 terabytes of storage.  While this is plenty doable with modern harddisks, *surely* you have something better to do with all that storage.

It will be better to store sorted list of, for each app, which users have the app installed.  This way you can use a set intersection algorithm to *compute* the entries of the matrix implicitly rather quickly.

You'll need to be more specific about what you're going to do with this data downstream in order to get recommendations on how to represent it.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I was thinking of storing the resulting matrix using techniques for storing sparse matrices (like "coordinates"), to save disk space (since each user typically has at most ~200 apps installed). My final purpose is to (given an app name) specify if the app is of certain type or not, by checking if the apps -installed together with it freqquently- are of that certain type. Each app will be marked with a boolean field/property, say "isTypeX".

Comment: @Metallica: It's probably not very sparse.  When A is sparse, A A^T often isn't.

Comment: For a single app (the input), I need to go through the list of apps with the "correlation count" greater than a threshold. So do you think I can do that with your suggested solution (set intersection)? If yes, can you explain a bit more?

Comment: @Metallica: List of pairs?  Or you've fixed one of the two apps you're taking the correlation of?

Comment: yes, I think I need a list of pairs, and I get one of the two apps as the input: I recieve "app3" as input, and I will say "app3" is of type X, because "app4" and "app5" which are also installed by most of users who installed "app3" are of type X.

Comment: If your threshold's big enough, a random sampling strategy should work.  If not, iterate over all apps A and all users of A and figure out how many of those use every other app.

Comment: Random sampling? how could it work? I'm not that familiar with statistical concepts, but random sampling doesn't guarantee that all elements with a certain property (like meaningful relation) will be chosen. Does it? By the way, iterating over all apps and all users will be of the order O(n^2), plus the cost of creating the first sorted list (users of each app) which will be O(n), so in total, the complexity will be O(n^3), the same as creating the matrix that I was talking about. Am I right?

Comment: If your threshold is 1000, sampling 10% of your users and inspecting all pairs that come up at least 50 times gets (using the Chernoff bound) all but a fraction 2.17 * 10^-7 of the desired app pairs.  That's better than a one-in-four-million chance of missing one particular pair.

Comment: Separately, sure, it's O(n^3).  The best thing to do when you start programming is to forget about these sorts of bounds, though, since they often depend on parameters (like n here) that don't describe the input with enough detail to estimate the complexity of your program accurately.  A better metric would be the number of (user, app) pairs you're looking at.  The method I gave takes time proportional to the sum of the squares of the number of apps each user has installed **always**.

Comment: My threshold is a PERCENTAGE of all users of an app (let's say 90% of users). I mean, I can say "app1 probably is a malware, because 95% of users who have app1, also have app4/app5/app6 which are malware". That seems the only way for defining apps "often installed with" a particuar app, do you know any other method for specifying that? (similar to "users who bought x, also bought y") If I use sampling 10% of users, do you think I can rely on that 10%, for extracting this "often installed with" with an acceptable degree of confidence?

Comment: By the way, I think "collaborative filtering" is what Amazon uses for purchase recommendation ("users who bought x, also bought y"). Can I make use of that?

Comment: As Wikipedia says: "Item-based collaborative filtering invented by Amazon.com (users who bought x also bought y), proceeds in an item-centric manner:
1.Build an item-item matrix determining relationships between pairs of items
2. Infer the tastes of the current user by examining the matrix and matching that user's data" Are they keeping the same huge matrix?

Comment: @Metallica: OK, so you're trying to extract a sort of implication graph from the dataset.  (Note that this information is essential but is **nowhere** in your question.)  I'd do the random sampling thing on the more popular apps (you'll get very little information loss here) and brute-force the less popular apps (this won't take too long because you've thinned out the data substantially).  "Collaborative filtering" is based on finding a low-rank approximation to the feature matrix; people seem to be happy enough with its output.  Formally, though, it solves a slightly different problem.